# What sort of white rock with lots of small holes is this?

Tags: sea, fossil-identification

This interesting pebble caught my eye the other day when I was wandering around on an Anglesey beach in Wales, UK but I haven't a clue what sort of rock it is and what has caused the little holes in it.

Parts of it are smooth while others are covered in holes (see below)

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated - I am just really curious :)

[image]

Comment: Maybe this is consisted of shells of dead sea life.

Comment: This will be an excellent question for the new [Earth Science SE](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/36296/earth-science) which should be up and running very soon.

Comment: @ChrisMueller feel free to move it to there (if that is possible) I want as many people as possible to have an input on this - I have really been intrigued by all the answers I have received so far

Answer (score 7):

That looks like fossilised coral (possibly a sponge?), the outside is smooth because it's been worn down by the erosion of the sea.

There is quite a lot of fossilised corral on the north Wales coast, it was once a [shallow, tranquil, tropical Carboniferous sea](http://www.bgs.ac.uk/research/ukgeology/angleseyNorthWales.html)

The Carboniferous period from [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carboniferous):

> The Carboniferous is a geologic period and system that extends from
>   the end of the Devonian Period, about 358.9 ± 0.4 million years ago,
>   to the beginning of the Permian Period, about 298.9 ± 0.15 Ma

Making it about 300,000,000 years old!

It's a very nice specimen BTW

Comment: forgot to ask, does it have a proper (scientific) name? or is it simply called "a fossilised coral" ? Would it be possible to estimate its age? (I guess this has to be done by taking it to an expert in the field)?

Comment: I don't know. I would guess it would be simply called "a fossil". I am not a geologist, though I do have geologist friends (I'll ask them). I've added details from Wikipedia on the period, I don't understand the age notation they're using, anyone?

Comment: @Bo5ao, There are several processes which result in fossils; some result in rocks while other don't (technically). Without knowing what kind of fossil it is, it's impossible to say whether it counts as a rock!

Comment: @Liam, Are you referring to the "298.9 ± 0.15 Ma" bit? Ma is short for Megaannum in this context, which is 1 million years.

Comment: Thank you for all your replies guys. I was just wondering should I leave the thread open to see if anyone else has something to say about it? In either case I have learned a bit more about this little gem. I will also get in touch with a friend of mine whom I believe works in the field of geology and will update you guys when I find out what it is

Comment: What about the + bit? @BrianS. I tried to google an answer but it's not something that is easy to search for!

Comment: @Bo5ao, yes if you want.

Comment: @Liam, "±" is the "plus or minus" symbol. "298.9 ± 0.15" means "298.9 - 0.15 or 298.9 + 0.15", though in most usages it means "anywhere from 298.9 - 0.15 to 298.9 + 0.15" -- it's giving an approximate range on the possible values.

Comment: @Liam did you mean that the rock is 300,000,000 years old? Wow!

Comment: There is a fair amount of **if's** in that: but *if* it's a coral and that coral *is* from the Carboniferous period, that period ended 300,000,000 years ago. So there is a fair chance that,yes it is 300,000,000 years old.